# Change initial Shinyapps "Please wait" message

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps, shinyjs

How can we change the initial "Please wait" message when an app starts up on shinyapps?
I am referring to the startup message of shinyapps.io, not packages like Waiter or shinybusy (for example) because the initial message "Please wait" still remaining when using theses packages (Waiter or shinybusy).

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think there is any way you can do so as of today. The message is shown before your app is loaded. That means the message is shown before running any part of your code. It means your code is irrelevant to the message, so you can't.